# Edges are hidden by the nodes

Tags: python, networkx

If I generate small nodes (see Figure node_size=100), the edges are not hidden by the nodes.
But if I increase the size of the nodes (see Figure node_size=1000) they cover the edges.

How can I adjust the position of end points of the edges such that they are not hidden by the nodes?

Code for reproduction of figure, using networkx 2.4, python3:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

G=nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_node(0,pos=(0,0.8))
G.add_node(1,pos=(0,0))
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(1,0)

pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_size = 100, nodelist=[0], node_color = 'r')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_size = 100, nodelist=[1], node_color = 'b')

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.7',edgelist = [(0,1)], width = 2)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.7',edgelist = [(1,0)], width = 2)

ax.set_axis_off()
fig.set_tight_layout('tight')
fig.savefig('test_hidden' + '.png')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout way to show the directed graph is to pass an  `alpha` parameter to `draw_networkx_nodes`, like so:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_size = 1000, nodelist=[0], node_color = 'r', alpha = 0.5)
```

This gives the following figure:

[image]